# How to explain BSTS models to non stats person?

Tags: r, time-series, bsts

I am using `BSTS` for building time series models. I am using exogenous variables also.

`BSTS` stands for Bayesian structural time series.

While, I am mostly not sure how bsts works e.g. how it picks trend, seasonality and coefficient for exogenous variables.

I know the `MCMC` part. But not able to connect it with `BSTS`. This means that I am not sure how `BSTS` uses `MCMC` in estimating trend, seasonality and variable coefficients. How `BSTS` uses `MCMC` during the forecast phase?

Is there some easy to understand explantion for understanding the working of BSTS?

Any explanation will help.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain BSTS also to people here....